# Not getting Ouytput of Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am not getting output of this procedure

```
   ALTER PROC [dbo].[SPTaxRepOutPrtWs]
    @DTS            DATETIME
    ,@DTE           DATETIME
    ,@VTypeStr      VARCHAR(200)
    ,@AcntStr       VARCHAR(200)
    ,@IsSummary     CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @nstrSQL                    NVARCHAR(4000)
        ,@nstrSQLPara               NVARCHAR(4000)
        ,@chr13                     CHAR(1)
        ,@StrVtypeCond              NVARCHAR(200)

IF @VTypeStr <> '**+'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VTypeStr = (''''+REPLACE(@VTypeStr,'+',''',''')+'''')
END

SELECT @StrVtypeCond = (CASE WHEN @VTypeStr = '**+' THEN '1=1' ELSE 'A.V_Type IN (' +@VTypeStr+ ')' END)

SELECT @nstrSQLPara = '@DTS DATETIME, @DTE DATETIME, @VTypeStr VARCHAR(200), @AcntStr VARCHAR(200), @IsSummary CHAR(1)'

SELECT @nstrSQL = 
    +'SELECT A.Prt_Ac,ISNULL(B.Descript,'''') AS Descript,A.V_Type,A.V_No,A.Date,A.Tot_Amt,A.Quantity'+@chr13 
    +'FROM Sales A'+@chr13
    +'  LEFT OUTER JOIN Party B ON A.Prt_Ac=B.Prt_Code'+@chr13
    +'WHERE A.Date BETWEEN @DTS AND @DTE'+@chr13
    +'AND '+@StrVtypeCond

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @nstrSQL, @nstrSQLPara, @DTS, @DTE, @VTypeStr, @AcntStr, @IsSummary
RETURN  
END
```

Comment: What are you getting? Are you getting columns with no rows? What kind of parameters are you providing? remember: if you concatenate anything eith NULL it's NULL. I suggest you at least add a `PRINT @nstrSQL` and see if it's what you expect - that would be some very basic troubleshooting

Comment: "Command(s) completed successfully." getting this only

Comment: The script you have there will create a stored procedure. To call it you need to use something like `EXEC SPTaxRepOutPrtWs ` + variables.

Comment: `EXEC SPTaxRepOutPrtWs '4-1-2017','3-31-2018','1B','','S'`

Comment: I have executed procedure but i am getting only 
 
"Command(s) completed successfully."

Comment: and I am expecting some Columns and Rows as output.

Comment: You never assign a value to `@chr13`, so when you use this to create your SQL string, you will be concatenating string with null, which yields null. Since you are passing NULL to `sp_executesql`, no results are returned

Comment: Yes, Now getting .Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As [GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) has mentioned in the comments, you declare a `CHAR(1)` variable called `@chr13` which is never set to any value and therefore is `NULL`.

When you then concatenate that variable with other values (the result of which is also `NULL`) and assign the result to `@nstrSQL`, this variable also becomes `NULL`. So then when you pass `@nstrSQL` to `SP_EXECUTESQL`, it is a NULL parameter and so you get no results.